# How to convert .txt to .idx3-ubyte format?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, neural-network, mnist, conv-neural-network

I am doing a project based on Convolutional Neural Networks and I am using MNisT database for the training images and also for the test data. I want to do this for Kannada Digits, but the format which I used for the Dataset is .txt and the base code which I have taken only the idx3-ubyte format. 
Please suggest me any tool that can convert the .txt files to .idx3-ubyte.

Answer (score 2):

The format for the idx3-ubyte files is published on [Yann LeCun's Site](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)

It should be pretty trivial to write the file format given that you are planning on building a CNN ;-)

Other than that, .txt simply says that it's a text file. It's impossible to provide more assistance without understanding how the text file is laid out. In particular, how is the binary data from each image stored in a text file ? Is it B64 encoded for example ? Or ascii-hex ?

Comment: Hi, please I don't understand this answer.
So, I have a txt of labels, which goes from 0 to 100.
And I have a txt of my images, why are 64 x 64, then I have lines of 64*64 numbers from 0 to 255, then break line and next image and so on, how should I convert it ? I don't understand

Comment: Have you looked here: http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/ ? At the bottom of the page is a section marked FILE FORMATS FOR THE MNIST DATABASE. In this section it explains exactly what file format is expected. Most important among these is that the files are binary files and the images are expected to be 28x28 pixels so you will need to resize your 64x64 data to 28x28. You'll then need to write some code to convert your text file into the format at the link provided - which is trivial.

Comment: Thank you, but that's really my doubt. I'm looking to convert from a set of images to that kind of file. I'm not expert in this field so that's why I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: Do you have the original images ? If so, best to convert them to 28x28 in a graphics package. If you only have the text files then it will be very hard for you to proceed without some coding skills.

Comment: I have my original images, all converted to 28x28, what should I do now ?

Comment: You need to convert them into the right format and concatenate them. Do you have any programming skills with any language ?

Comment: Yes, C++, Java, PHP, C... I just don't understand the way to convert it clearly

Comment: So basically you need to do this:  Get images in 28x28 format (done), save them in a format that you understand and can write code to parse. I suggest PPM which is a text format (details here http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) .  Then write a C or C++ program to read the text files and write them out in binary format as specified on the website I mentioned. You need two files, an image file and an index file. The text file format is above, the binary file format is at the page I already linked to.  If you still don't know what to do you will need to ask a far more specific question